# Not sure about which laptop cooler to choose

Tags: laptop, cooling

I have an ASUS N56VB and have been researching laptop coolers for a while now (or maybe even too much).
I checked the areas where the laptop overheats when playing games and noticed that it happens only on the left side. Even the hard drive, which is on the bottom right, is unaffected.
Also, I think the vents are not at the bottom of the laptop but on it's left side.
There are of course a lot of brands which make the choice even harder.

Considering those circumstances, I am not sure whether to buy a cooling pad with 1 fan, 2 or 4 fans. 1 fan lies always in the center, and the heating occurs on the left side only. 2 fans might be sufficient. 4 fans, while at the right areas, seem redundant.

Here are some pictures:

Some measurements - 
[image: Measurements]

The side vents - 
[image: Side vents]

I thought that maybe this will be good:
[http://www.amazon.com/BlueFinger%C2%AE-Arrival-Notebook-2200-4000%C2%B110%25RPM-Ultra-portable/dp/B0148IKWYS/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1455965509&sr=8-1&keywords=Bluefinger+2+in+1](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0148IKWYS)
As it has both a cooling pad and a cooler on the side, but there are not enough reviews for this product.

Another good product is this:
[http://www.amazon.com/Cooling-TeckNet-Notebook-Adjustable-Temperature/dp/B016CL2F5S/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1455965555&sr=8-1&keywords=TeckNet%C2%AE+Gaming+Laptop](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016CL2F5S)
Mainly because of the temperature display and the on/off switch (which hopefully also turns off the fans themselves).

Or perhaps this one (or something similar? there could be others that are way better):
[http://www.amazon.com/Thermaltake-Massive23-Notebook-Oversized-CLN0015/dp/B003ZUXXWO/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1455965583&sr=8-1&keywords=Thermaltake+Massive23](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003ZUXXWO)
Perhaps one fan is better? I'm not sure.

So far I'm thinking about the BlueFinger cooler (mainly because it is pad&side cooler) but the lack of reviews is disturbing. I would really appreciate your assistance as I have never bought a laptop cooler before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are my recommendations:
1, [LotFancy 13-15.6 inch laptop cooler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00RE5SO8E)
  - Dual fan
  - 73% 5 star rating (out of 176)
  - $16.30

2, [Cooler Master NotePal X2](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002MU1ZRS)
- Single fan
- 78% overall positive rating (out of 7,332)
- $29.99

3, [EGOGO 12"-17" Laptop Cooler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0179P8UGE)
- Quad fan
- Dual controlled cooling zones
- Dual USB port
- $19.99

Now that the Amazon links are working, I can honestly say the [TekNet](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016CL2F5S) cooler looks best for your situation. It has about as many features as you can possibly get in a laptop cooler, and it has a moderate number of reviews, most of which are positive. As for the side cooler, I would recommend using the TekNet with a separate side cooler, so you can have all the neat features instead of compromising.

The [HAVIT HV-F2061 Mini LED USB Vacuum Turbine Air Extracting Cooling Fan Cooler](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00W0YZS6K) has:
- Temperature LCD
- Automatic/Manual adjustable speed
- Quad head dispenser
- Fits almost any laptop
- $19.99

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, and thank you for your answer! I will fix the links now. As for your answer, any reason why you chose these two coolers? There is nothing special about them (so it seems). I'm looking for something that will be the best for the price (and should mention that money is not really an issue here, so even $50 would be fine, as long as there really is a reason to spend that much).

Comment: Since I can't edit my comment: 1. when saying special I mean other functions such as on/off switch (which I see both of the coolers you suggested have), temperature display, ability to adjust fan speeds, etc. 2. why would the LotFancy be better? Because it has 2 fans? 3. Should I buy that side cooler (like in the BlueFinger) separately, or just but the BlueFinger pad? I'm not even sure if they will work, how to connect them.

Comment: To be honest, there are too many laptop coolers on the market, and I only own one laptop cooler, so I can't give you much perspective. Laptop coolers in general do not have many features, and for some reason, usually come with blue back-lighting, if at all. If I listed every product I thought was worthy of your consideration, the list would be a million entries long. I'm just giving you what I can.

Comment: What would you recommend for a similarly-shaped laptop that gets hot in the center?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the models linked here have fans mounted in a fashion that makes them work like axial fans with a big dead spot¹ in the middle and directly blowing at the mostly closed surface or trying to suck air from it, which probably causes more turbulence in the fan itself than actual cooling of the device. I don't think this is a very efficient design, neither do I think that the mentioned extracting cooler fan helps support the CPU cooler in the laptop doing it's job better. It tries to get the hot air out faster, but doesn't help getting fresh and cool air into the system.

We had some older very hot running laptops in the office here in Germany. I bought an [Arctic NC](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002G3FRG6) suitable for 14 and 15 inch sized laptops which made it run significantly cooler and I have used it since then for most of the laptops I worked with in the office. It's rather small and mostly quiet. I would recommend looking for such a device that works more like a radial design and covers the entire surface without any dead spots. The downside of this particular cooler is, that your laptop only stands on two points on this fan which may be bit unstable in some cases compared to the other designs.

[image]

As I said I live in Germany where it doesn't get very hot and our offices are outside of town, my co-worker in Hungary living in a not well ventilated [apartment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plattenbau) had more severe heat problems with the same laptop model (trying to cool with +40°C fresh air). So it also depends on where you live.

---

1. [TMD fans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tip-magnetic_driving) were proposed as a solution to the dead spot problem more than 10 years ago, but never got as popular as the radial based designs you can find today.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really understand, how does this cover the entire laptop surface? Also do you think it's possible to use both this and a cooling pad? I already purchased the TekNet.

Comment: If you look at the other pictures of the product over at Amazon you can see that the fans suck in air from the top and blow it through the vents beneath the laptop, it's very similar to what you call a cooling pad. Using both would not make much sense, I guess.